# Proof: sum, multiplication and division of two periodic function

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Proof that the sum, multiplication and division of two periodic function with the same period, is again a periodic function

Please help, I need these three proofs for my calculus homework

Comment: Hint: Suppose the functions are $f, g$ with period $p$.
What is $f(x+p)+g(x+p)$ equal to?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Just show, for example, that $(f+g)(x+T)=(f+g)(x)$. But that's simple, isn't it? You are given that $f(x+T)=f(x)$ and $g(x+T)=g(x)$. So add both sides of these equations.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $f,g$ be periodic with period $p$, meaning that $f(x+p)=f(x)$ and $g(x+p)=g(x)$ for all real $x$.

What can you say about periodicity $h=f+g, k=f \cdot g, m = f/g$? E.g. how is $h(x+p) = f(x+p) + g(x+p)$ related to $h(x)$?